# How to to send mail using gmail in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, email, gmail

I try again and again to test sending an email from localhost but I still cannot. I don't know anymore how to do it. I try search to find solution but I cannot find one. I edited config/mail.php:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => ['address' => 'myemail@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Do not Reply'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail "Pretend"
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
    | web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
    | you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
    |
    */

    'pretend' => false,

];
`
```

and I edited `.env` file like this already:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

It still produced error like this:
[image]

Comment: you need to create app password for this.. have you enabled two step verification for your gmail account?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. So we I have to enabled in my gmail account first?

Comment: @SRENGKhorn iam also getting the same error. did u got solution for this ?

Comment: @prudhvi259 test it with mail gun https://www.mailgun.com/

Comment: How to [Send Email in Laravel](https://devnote.in/how-to-send-email-in-laravel-with-example/) with Example

Answer (score 180):

first login to your gmail account and under `My account > Sign In And Security > Sign In to google`, enable `two step verification`, then you can generate `app password`, and you can use that app password in `.env` file.

Your `.env` file will then look something like this

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=apppassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Don't forget to run `php artisan config:cache` after you make changes in your `.env` file.

Comment: After follow your advise this occurred: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
#10013]

Comment: are you using app password or your own gmail password? or if you have any internet security software like `norton, kaspersky` etc, disable it and test if sending an email works or not.

Comment: Yes, I am using app password by google and I disabled McAfee but nothing happen.

Comment: look, there seems no problem with the code, its just a security issue..just try and run `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan config:clear` once and check

Comment: try turning off your window defender

Comment: do not forget to allow gmail to send te email outside https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Works perfectly on Laravel 5.2 as of January 2017.

Comment: @Sid - App Password for device based, then why we need app password?

Comment: Two years later, only your answer remembers me the `php artisan config:cache`. Thank you!

Comment: App passwords you get here https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords and sign in described here https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Comment: `.env` settings of @Sid + Gmail's 2-step verification + 'custom name' app password just solved my problem.  Running Laravel 5.3 with Norton Internet Security on Windows 10.

Comment: Worked perfectly on Laravel 5.7 as of Jan 2019. Do **not** forget to use `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: after sending 20 emails i am getting the same issue....for first 20 emails is working properly but after that its throwing same error.... is there any solution ?

Comment: This method is outdated and no longer works.

Answer (score 22):

Try using *sendmail* instead of *smtp* driver (according to these recommendations: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-emails-with-laravel-4-gmail--net-36105)

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=apppassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 17):

All you have to do is just edit in you.env file, that's it.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=<your_email_address>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<your_gmail_app_password_>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

for app password goto 
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

and genearate your app pasword and save for future use. because once you generate app password you cannot re-edit password or change same app password.(you can create multiple app password)

Comment: what's the different ssl with tls?

Comment: I found that ssl direct email to spam but tls not

Answer (score 16):

This is working sample that i have tried :

Open your `mail.php` under `config` folder then fill with this option :

```php
'driver'     => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host'       => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port'       => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from'       => ['address' =>'youremail@mail.com', 'name' => 'Email_Subject'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username'   => env('MAIL_USERNAME','yourusername@mail.com'),
'password'   => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','youremailpassword'),
'sendmail'   => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

Open your `.env` file under `root` project. Also edit this file following above
option such

```sh
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp    
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com   
MAIL_PORT=587      
MAIL_USERNAME=youremailusername
MAIL_PASSWORD=youremailpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

After that clear your config by running this command

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Restart your local server

Try visit your route with controller contains mail function at first
time it still error `Authentication Required`. You need to login via
your gmail account to authorize untrusted connection. Visit this [link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)
to authorize

Answer (score 7):

if you still could be able to send mail after setting all configs right and get forbidden or timeout errors you could set the `allow less secure apps to access your account` in gmail. you can follow how to [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Comment: Yes, that is the best solution. I had all the previous settings, but suddenly I couldn't login anymore. Allowing less secure apps to access the account worked for me.

Comment: I was getting a 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted and this solved my issue

Answer (score 3):

**Note: Laravel 7 replaced MAIL_DRIVER by MAIL_MAILER**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp    
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com   
MAIL_PORT=587      
MAIL_USERNAME=yourgmailaddress
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourgmailpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Allow less secure apps from "Google Account" 
 - https://myaccount.google.com/
 - Settings
 - Less secure app access (Turn On)

Flush cache config:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

For Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Note: In 2022, Google removed Less Secure Apps. I'm searching for an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

in bluehost i could not reset password; with this driver worked:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

Comment: In cpanel hosting use this drive works me

Answer (score 1):

you need to enable first the App password of your google account -> security section [link](https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/webcreateaccount?hl=en-GB&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=SignUp)

then the app password that will be generated copy it and paste it in to .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=account@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=app_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Answer (score 0):

your `MAIL_PASSWORD=must a APPpasword` 
after change the **.env** stop the server then clear configuratios cahce php artisan config:cahce and start the server again

reference
[Cannot send message without a sender address in laravel 5.2 I have set .env and mail.php both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873613/cannot-send-message-without-a-sender-address-in-laravel-5-2-i-have-set-env-and/38781068#38781068)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using email password then you should replace it with app password.for setting APP password you need to enable the 2 step authentication before setting password which can be disabled later.

Also make sure that you have allowed less secure app in setting section.For additional info you can follow how to [here](https://svikramjeet.blogspot.com/2019/04/sending-emails-in-laravel-with-gmail.html)

Answer (score 0):

Working for me after trying various combinations.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=passowrd
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

It is necessary to generate application password https://myaccount.google.com/security and us it as `MAIL_PASSWORD` environment variable.

I found about about this by checking error code from google server, which was use-full and lead me to [this](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?p=BadCredentials&visit_id=636941508101278441-4266635081&rd=2#cantsignin) webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try adding to laravel these 2 lines:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=you@email.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="you@email.com"
```

After this run this comand to flush mail cache config:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

`MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` 
`MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com`
`MAIL_PORT=587`
`MAIL_USERNAME=yourmail@gmail.com`
`MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword`
`MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`
`MAIL_FROM_NAME='Name'`

**allow less secure apps to access** your account in the Gmail security setting.

Answer (score -1):

If you're developing on an XAMPP, then you'll need an SMTP service to send the email. Try using a MailGun account. It's free and easy to use.

Answer (score -1):

The problem for me is that for some reason the username/password came NULL from mail config. 
To check that before sending a email check with the follow code:

```
dd(Config::get('mail'));
```

If your username/password came nulled just set with:

```
Config::set('mail.username', 'yourusername');
Config::set('mail.password', 'yourpassword');
```

Answer (score -1):

These configuration works for me you use port 25,465,587

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=apppassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score -2):

Just change MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null to MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

And run this command "php artisan config:cache"