# laravel - the from email address received differ from what is set

Tags: email, laravel-5

I'm trying to make the laravel default "forget password" to work, after a long try of setting up, I finally got the email sent. Cheers! but I have a question now, the sender email address is not what I set.
I want the from address to be my gmail address but when I received the email, the from address is "myusername@server214.web-hosting.com". Any hint, what is wrong?

in my mail.php:

```
'driver' => 'sendmail',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 587,
'from' => ['address' => "myemail@gmail.com", 'name' => "myname"],
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
'password' => 'password',
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the send mail driver so your Gmail account isn't use

Use the `SMTP` driver instead

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail

Comment: i get errors when i change to "smtp"

Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 269:
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Network is unreachable #101]
in StreamBuffer.php line 269
at Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() in StreamBuffer.php line 62
at Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(array('protocol' => 'tcp', 'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com', 'port' => '587', 'timeout' => '30', 'blocking' => '1', 'tls' => true, 'type' => '1', 'stream_context_options' => array())) in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 113

Comment: Now the problem is in the configuration but the driver is correct. you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515245/how-to-to-send-mail-using-gmail-in-laravel-5-1

Comment: no luck with the link u gave. I tried to change the host, from, username, password to my own domain email address info, it works perfectly, but fail with gmail. whats wrong with the gmail?

Comment: You have to enable Gmail less secure app https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en or check how to configure your Gmail account but now it's not related to laravel