# Sending email in Laravel with form and with multiple addresses

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.1

my focus is to send an email with a form where you can insert:
name,
last name,
from(any email),
to   (my email).
First of all I have tried using the google configuration(see on internet), but the email don't send, the result is a blank page.
I must configuration only services.php and .env ?

Comment: Check this link : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515245/how-to-to-send-mail-using-gmail-in-laravel-5-1]

Answer (score 1):

Nothing too complicated, have you read [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail)?

First of all you need to setup your configuration inside `config/mail.php` (as `'driver'`) or in your `.env` (as `MAIL_DRIVER`).

You may start setting it to `sendmail`, but consider using `smtp` or a service like mailgun as soon as you go online.

Second step is the creation of a view, as example in `app/resources/views/emails` (the snippet that follows would use `app/resources/views/emails/reminder.blade.php`), however you can name it whatever you prefer.

Then in your controller all you have to do is just:

```php
$email = 'email@foo.bar';
$name  = 'John Doe';

Mail::send('emails.reminder', [], function ($m) {
    $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');
    $m->to($email, $name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
});
```

Where the array passed as second argument may contain additional data that you may want to pass to the view.

**// EDIT**
Sorry, I didn't understand you meant to use gmail.

In that case you may need to configure smtp settings. As an example, if you would use `.env` for settings it should reflect something like:

```php
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mybeautifulpasswordthatnooneknows
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```