# Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 268:

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I try to send an email from my laravel site I get this error

> Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 268: Connection could not be established with host lin01.hkdns.co.za [ #0]

all my details is right. my env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=lin01.hkdns.co.za
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=info@mysite.co.za
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

In my mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'info@mysite.co.za'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Info'),
],

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],
```

Did I miss something or is this a problem on my server?

Answer (score 3):

Sometime it's possible to be "cache" in the laravel.

**Use this command and try again:**

```
php artisan config:clear
```

If not work, try to restart you xampp.

Another option to check if the problem is with your host or your configuration is to use a Gmail server to send a test email.

Puts this in your `.env`

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=apppassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Create or use any gmail account and enable the [less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) more information [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

> first login to your gmail account and under My account > Sign In And
>   Security > Sign In to google, enable two step verification, then you
>   can generate app password, and you can use that app password in .env
>   file.
>
> Your .env file will then look something like this
>
> `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com` 
>   `MAIL_PORT=587`
>   `MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com`
>   `MAIL_PASSWORD=apppassword`
>   `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`
>
> Don't forget to run `php artisan config:cache` after you make changes in
>   your .env file (or restart your server).

Source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515245/how-to-to-send-mail-using-gmail-in-laravel-5-1)

Comment: I get this error now `ErrorException in StreamBuffer.php line 94: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`

Comment: If you are using Docker, consider restart your container too!