# Laravel App not sending email via Sendmail on Wamp depsite SMTP

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have set up a Laravel app on my Wamp server. We are on Laravel 5 (which we have migrated from an initial Laravel 4 app).

In the .env file a SMTP is declared (the same than the one we use on our online application) 
Yet it seems the app doesn't want to send email. For example when I try to make a password recovery, I get this : "
Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 307:
Process could not be started "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 268:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829812/swift-transportexception-in-streambuffer-php-line-268)

Comment: I have already cleared the cache, and I don't use gmail to send email. Not a duplicate.

Comment: It doesn't matter which smtp you are using. Try clearing cache and restarting your wamp/

Comment: @Exterminator I already tried both. I read those question before even posting...