# laravel: cant receive email in gmail using mail

Tags: php, email, gmail, laravel-5.3

I'm using laravel and i can successfully send mail without an error but the problem is i'm not receiving any emails and I've already tried it via localhost and free hosting.

here is my env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:nt0cJ462Ps/981BuAA368UO3pAZPrYLbVAzKpbyLhwg=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
 QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=
```

Comment: `MAIL_DRIVER=SMTP`

Comment: Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. But my credentials are correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to to send mail using gmail in Laravel 5.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515245/how-to-to-send-mail-using-gmail-in-laravel-5-1)

Answer (score 0):

try to change MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail to  MAIL_DRIVER=smtp on your env file .