# Laravel: Mail connection error

Tags: php, laravel, email, ssl, shared-hosting

i have a laravel 5.2 project working in a BLUEHOST shared server, and i having troubles configuring my email app, i'm not using another mail service (like mailgun) just the laravel's service, i tried it with my gmail account and their configurations and this worked fine (just for testing), so i need setup it with the BLUEHOST mail service.

I have this data form my email account configuration provided by BLUEHOST:

```
Email Settings

Mail Server Username: info@domain.com

Standard (without SSL)

Incoming Mail Server: mail.domain.com
Supported Ports: 143 (IMAP), 110 (POP3)
Outgoing Mail Server: mail.domain.com
Supported Port: 26 (server requires authentication)

Private (with SSL)

Incoming Mail Server: box668.bluehost.com (SSL)
Supported Ports: 993 (IMAP), 995 (POP3)
Outgoing Mail Server: box668.bluehost.com (SSL)
Supported Port: 465 (server requires authentication)
Supported Incoming Mail Protocols: POP3, IMAP
Supported Outgoing Mail Protocols: SMTP
```

My config/mail.php:

```
<?php

return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mail.domain.com'),

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

    'from' => ['address' => 'info@domain.com', 'name' => 'Some name'],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

];
```

My .env email setup:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.domain.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=info@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=info123+
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

I tried both options (Standard (without SSL) and Private (with SSL)) however i got this error:

```
Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 269:
Connection could not be established with host mail.domain.com [ #0]
```

What's wrong? or my customer must buy a Mailgun's subscription?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this out for myself! I'm going to reiterate what Matthijs said and then my original contribution is bolded below -- that's what fixed it for me.

This is what I did, I don't know what you've already tried, but this worked for me.

I ssh'd into my server and cd into my laravel app. I should mention I'm hosted on Vultr not Bluehost, but it should work the same... I think?

```
cd /var/www/laravel
```

You're going to want to open your env file and make some configurations.

```
ls -a
nano .env
```

Make the changes on your server and then run the artisan config cache command

```
php artisan cache:command
```

If you're running through GMail, you need to make you're accepting less secure applications.

If this still isn't working then you need to actually go into your **config folder and alter your mail.php** file to match the information in your env file. Here's what mine looks like:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),


'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),


'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),


'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'spkellydev@gmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Sean!'),
],


'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),


'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),


'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

and then I have some custom settings under that which shouldn't be relevant at all. Hope this helps, friend!

Comment: From what i know, there is no command such as: ```php artisan cache:command```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime it's possible to be "cache" in the laravel.

**Use this command and try again:**

```
php artisan config:clear
```

If not work, try to restart you xampp.

Another option to check if the problem is with your host or your configuration is to use a Gmail server to send a test email.

Puts this in your `.env`

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=apppassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Create or use any gmail account and enable the [less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) more information [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

> first login to your gmail account and under My account > Sign In And
>   Security > Sign In to google, enable two step verification, then you
>   can generate app password, and you can use that app password in .env
>   file.
>
> Your .env file will then look something like this
>
> `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com` 
>   `MAIL_PORT=587`
>   `MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com`
>   `MAIL_PASSWORD=apppassword`
>   `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`
>
> Don't forget to run `php artisan config:cache` after you make changes in
>   your .env file (or restart your server).

Source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515245/how-to-to-send-mail-using-gmail-in-laravel-5-1)

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I tried with GMAIL and it works fine (just for testing), but this app needs to send mails from BLUEHOST server :(
PD: i executed php artisan config:clear and it does'nt work too