# Laravel :Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username using 2 possible authenticators

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I've configured to gmail SMTP server to send email. Account less secure app turned ON, also Recapture  enabled. Here is the mail.php configuration.

This code working fine on local server. But when i tried to in godaddy server i saw the following Error :

```
 (1/1) Swift_TransportException Failed to authenticate on SMTP server
 with username "xxxx@gmail.com" using 2 possible authenticators in AuthHandler.php (line 181)
```

> .env (mail part)

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

> Mail.php

```
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'xxxx@gmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'xxxx'),
    ],


    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'TLS'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Its already answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515245/how-to-to-send-mail-using-gmail-in-laravel-5-1

Comment: how can you say that's the answer?
Did you see the title what problem i'm facing?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but my resolution was a bit different for the same error. Turns out my Swift configuration is fine. The IP from my server was blocked by Google as suspicious. I was able to clear it by visiting this link, then executing my mailer code from the server.
http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know this is an old thread but i came across a similar issue with **GoDaddy SMTP** with the **Laravel** application running on **AWS EC2**. The below code works for me maybe it will help you guys too.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST="relay-hosting.secureserver.net"
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME="<your_email@example.com>"
MAIL_PASSWORD="<your_password>"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="<your_email@example.com>"
```