# How can i use my email to get the message send by the guest in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have created a simple contact form, i just want to know how can i use my email inside this code to get the message of the guest directly to my email. Am using this form in laravel.
Here is contact form code:

```
This is my php code  

<?php

$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
    $website = "";
  } else {
    $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);

    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) {
      $websiteErr = "Invalid URL"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
  } else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
```

This is my html code
    <

```
h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
    <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
      Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
      <br><br>
      E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
      <br><br>
      Website: <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
      <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
      <br><br>
      Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
      <br><br>
      Gender:
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
    </form>
```

Also i want to know how to print a success message to the guest when they send the message. The success message should be printed below the contact form.

Comment: use PHP mail() function. Thanks.

Comment: You could have searched the site there's tones of here to show you how to send an email using php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail):

> Laravel provides a clean, simple API over the popular [SwiftMailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/) library with drivers for SMTP, Mailgun, SparkPost, Amazon SES, PHP's mail function, and sendmail, allowing you to quickly get started sending mail through a local or cloud based service of your choice.

You need to configure your webapp to use the `driver` you want, e.g. gmail or PHP's "mail" function. Please see other similar question as [How to to send mail using gmail in Laravel 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515245/how-to-to-send-mail-using-gmail-in-laravel-5-1).

Comment: I see no laravel in the question

Comment: @Borjante "Am using this form in laravel."....

Comment: Oh gosh... you are rigth. This must be one of the dirtiest forms I've seen in Laravel