# Laravel Swiftmailer: Authentication required

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

I'm working with laravel 5.4 and swiftmailer library to post a form to a gmail account but kept getting this exception:

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1
>   Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1
>   https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError e9sm4625463eda.52 -
>   gsmtp"

Please, how can i fix it?

P.S I'm new to laravel.

Thanks!

**mail.php**

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('ASTC', 'md.astcltd@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('ASTC', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('mdmail@gmail.com'),

    'password' => env('*****'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

**.env**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:xkMzNqLfYTohaUX7rcv/j0yd2NQB5RYMTWmcCGDqD+g=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mdmail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

**AppController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

//use Illuminate\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\ContactFormRequest;

class AppController extends Controller
{


    public function create(){
        return view('contact');
    }

    public function store(ContactFormRequest $request)
    {
        //Mail::send()
        // Mail::send('emails.contact', ['user' => $user],
        //  function ($m) use ($user) {
        //      $m->from('md.astcltd@gmail.com', 'ASTC Contact form');

        //      $m->to($user->'md.astcltd@gmail.com', 'Admin')->subject('Feedback from ASTC');
        // });

        \Mail::send('emails.contact',
        array(
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'user_message' => $request->get('message')
        ), function($message)
    {
        $message->from('clientsresponse@gmail.com');
        $message->to('mdmail@gmail.com', 'Admin')->subject('ASTC Feedback');
    });



        return \Redirect::route('contact')

        //session::flash('message', 'Thank you for contacting us!');
        ->with('message', 'Thank you for contacting us!');

    }
    // public function contact(Request $request) {

    //     

    // }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the steps in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515245/how-to-to-send-mail-using-gmail-in-laravel-5-1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to to send mail using gmail in Laravel 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515245/how-to-to-send-mail-using-gmail-in-laravel-5-1)

Answer (score 1):

You used the [`env()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#retrieving-environment-configuration) function incorrectly on the `mail.php` configuration.

```
'username' => env('mdmail@gmail.com'),
'password' => env('*****'),
```

The first parameter passes to `env()` function is the configuration key to search on the `.env` file. And the second parameter is optional, and it's a default value to be returned if the configuration key is not found on `.env`.

```
env('CONFIG_KEY', $default = null);
```

So if you configured your `.env` like this:

```
// .env
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=user@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=SuperSecretPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Your `mail.php` configuration should look like this instead:

```
// app/config/mail.php
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('ASTC', 'md.astcltd@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('ASTC', 'Example'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    ...
```

Also if your Gmail uses 2 step verification, you must [generate an App password](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords). And use this generated password on `MAIL_PASSWORD` configuration.

If you are not using 2 step verification, make sure that you [allow less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) to access your Gmail account.

Your host, port number, and encryption are already correct:

- Host: smtp.gmail.com
- Port: 465
- Encryption: SSL

Check this [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) to see the complete list of Gmail host and port numbers.

Hope this help!

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did include "env('CONFIG_KEY', $default = null);" in the mail.php file but i still get the same error message; Authentication required. Any possible solution?