# (1/1) Swift_TransportException Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

Tags: laravel, email

I want to send mail after registration.But I had faced this problem.Can anyone tell me how can I solve this problem?And I am uploading my env file here.

```html
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=kazibablubif@gmial.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=edkecsyimolpbuua
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error even when I changed and did `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I had done this

Answer (score 1):

Try 2 step verification and add generate **app password** and add it to your `.env` file

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32515570/2891689