# Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required "

Tags: laravel

I got stuck on this error. I am trying to configure SMTP mail on laravel.
I have this issue when I want to send the password reset link:-
[image]

I found the reference but I have make change on 'host' and 'port'

```
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mailtrap.io'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),
```

but I still have the same issue .

**My config/mail.php:**

```
 <?php

return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mailtrap.io'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: have you tried running `php artisan config:clear` after you changed values in your config?

Comment: yes.done with it but same problem. I tried run php artisan config:cache as well.

Comment: And you set both `MAIL_USERNAME `and `MAIL_PASSWORD` in your `.env` file?

Comment: did you set the mail login and password in the config or .env file?

Comment: alright. but now got different problem Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "xxx@gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators.

Comment: Are you trying to setup mailtrap or gmail? If gmail check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32515570/9193055) out.

Comment: yeah. another problem again "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded"