# Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send email in Laravel using Swift Mailer with markdown, i have been still trying from last 3 days but No Exact Solution found.

I have the .env file which is working properly in Local server. But, same env if I referred then I am getting above error.

I am not able to find what is wrong with my code.

Already Referred given solutions on google.

.env file:-

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local 
APP_KEY=xx 
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=xx
DB_DATABASE=xx
DB_USERNAME=xx
DB_PASSWORD=
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_ADDRESS=xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Not enough details, the problem might be on your code, maybe you are just not reading from the .env

Comment: What else you need to get this issue resolved?

Comment: has you created App password in google ?

Comment: You'll need to allow *third-party/ less-secure apps* in your gmail settings - https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: @TusharWalzade I allowed less secure apps in gmail settings. Still same error found..

I just need to ask a question. Is that like GMail blocked our IP address if we tried to sent email from other server..

I have my project on AWS..

Comment: Have you tried it using Yahoo mail? If so, is it working?

Comment: @TusharWalzade not yet. Let me try with that and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @TusharWalzade hey I am unable to resolve the error given by yahoo as well..

Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550

Comment: this may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515245/how-to-to-send-mail-using-gmail-in-laravel-5-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create app password in google [app password](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) and use that password.

App password is a 16-digit passcode that gives an app or device permission to access your Google Account.If you use 2-Step-Verification and are seeing a “password incorrect” error when trying to access your Google Account, an App password may solve the problem.
[source](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but, I am still struggling even after generating 16 digit passcode.

Comment: once try with another email service provider