# How to send mail with laravel through gmail smtp?

Tags: laravel, email

I want to make contact Us page in my website, i have successfully do it with mailtrap, but when i want to send with gmail smtp server , i receive nothing and i get no error. 
this is my .env mail config :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail
MAIL_PASSWORD=my_app_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

and code i use to send email:

```
    $obj=new \stdClass();       
    $obj->contenu=$request->input('contenu');
    $obj->objet=$request->input('objet');
    $obj->email=$request->input('email');
    $data=array('contenu'=>$obj->contenu,'email'=>$obj->email);
    Mail::send("front.contactUs",$data,function ($message) use ($obj){
        $message->from($obj->email);
        $message->to('salondesbelleslettres@gmail.com')
                ->subject($obj->objet);
    });
    if(count(Mail::failures())>0){
        return redirect()->back()->with('error','Votre demande na pas ete soumise');
    }else{
        return redirect()->back()->with('success','Merci de Nous Avoir Contacté');
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you enable less secure app access with your Google account? Learn more about this https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: yes, i have done it, and created password for my laravel app.

Comment: You need to read the documentation first. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to to send mail using gmail in Laravel 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515245/how-to-to-send-mail-using-gmail-in-laravel-5-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Need to change your `.env` file to something like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=apppassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

After completion of `.env` edit please enter this command in your terminal for clear cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

You need to generate app password, and you can use that app password in `.env` file.

**How to generate an App password:**

1. Go to your [Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/)
2. On the left navigation panel, click **Security**.
3. On the *Signing* in to *Google* panel, click **App passwords**.
   (Note: If you can't get to the page, 2-Step Verification is:
   Not set up for your account,
   Set up for security keys only)
4. At the bottom, click Select app and choose the app you’re using.
5. Click **Select device** and choose the device you’re using.
6. Click **Generate**
7. Follow the instructions to enter the App password (the 16 character code in the yellow bar) on your device.
8. Click **Done**.

Once you are finished, you won’t see that App password code again.

Note: You may not be able to create an App password for [less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255).

Answer (score 1):

These settings worked for me instead.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: i have also tried this setting but  nothing. please how did you get your password?

Comment: It's your email's password

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=youremailaddress@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=gtxajikwsqmlaqcr  // your app password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```