# can't send an email using laravel.?

Tags: laravel

in my projects i want when i create a user i want to send to him password  and role
 in email through gmail i try many solutions but nothing happen any help .there is no errors 
but i can't receive mail in gmail !!!!!

this is my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=--------@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=-----------
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

and this is mail.php:

```
<?php

    return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
|            "postmark", "log", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Markdown Mail Settings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
| theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
| of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
|
*/

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Log Channel
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you are using the "log" driver, you may specify the logging channel
| if you prefer to keep mail messages separate from other log entries
| for simpler reading. Otherwise, the default channel will be used.
|
*/

'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

];
```

and this is my loginMail.php:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Mail;

        use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
        use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
        use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
        use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

    class loginMail extends Mailable
    {
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
        * Create a new message instance.
        *
        * @return void
        *
        */


    public function __construct($password,$role)

    {
        $this->password=$password;
        $this->role=$role;

    }

    /**
        * Build the message.
        *
        * @return $this
        */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.login')->with('password','role');
    }
}
```

and this is login.blade.php:

```
@component('mail::message')
    # L'equipe de ########

    Bienvenue parmi notre equipe de Travail

    <p>Votre Mot de passe est:{{ $password }}</p>
    <p>Votre role dans notre projet est:{{ $role }}</p>


    Thanks,<br> 
    {{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

and this my controller function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    /**     $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:20',
            'email' =>'required|string|email|unique:users',
            'password'=> 'required|string|mn:6',
            'tel' => 'required|number',
            'role' => 'required'
                ]);*/

    return User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email'=> $request->email,
            'password'=> bcrypt($request->password),
            'tel'=> $request->tel,
            'role'=> $request->role

    ]);
    Mail::to($request->email)->send(new loginMail($request->password,$request->role));
}
```

Comment: try with mailtrap and see if it's a gmail problem or a your server problem

Comment: i try it same problem

Comment: does [FakeSMTP](http://nilhcem.com/FakeSMTP/) also didnt work? if so, something on the code. if yes, then the email is deemed as spam and discarded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to to send mail using gmail in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515245/how-to-to-send-mail-using-gmail-in-laravel)

Comment: Are you facing any error from laravel. if not then have you tried to change your port number to 587 from 2525 ?