# "How can i send email through gmail"

Tags: laravel

I am sending email through Gmail but it is given the error "unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection refused)".

my .env file is

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=587                              // my port also try 465
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@gmail.com            //my gmail id
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypasswrd                  //my password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Laravel Dev"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=dev@localhost.com
```

how can i resolve that error.

Comment: I am using laravel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to to send mail using gmail in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515245/how-to-to-send-mail-using-gmail-in-laravel)