# Laravel send forget password mail via breeze but not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting always the same error message when I am trying to use the "Breeze" Laravel Auth Forgot Passwort Method.
After entering my email adress I get the following error message:

Connection could not be established with host smtp.googlemail.com :stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Operation timed out)

I have already edited my .env correctly to:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Laravel"
```

and also added following configurations under config/mail.php

```
    'stream'=>[
        'ssl'=>[
            'allow_self_signed'=>true,
            'verify_peer'=>false,
            'verify_peer_name'=>false,
        ],
    ],
```

Also turn less security "ON" for my gmail account.

Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to to send mail using gmail in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515245/how-to-to-send-mail-using-gmail-in-laravel)

Comment: Hi steven! tried both method but still not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="mymail"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

// at terminal

```
php artisan config: cache
php artisan config: clear
```

//then at your maill account search "less secure app" then enable it and try again